# FluentD Can't Read Logs, 'log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.'

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logging, fluentd, efk

I am trying to deploy an EFK stack on top of an application that stores it's logs in /var/opt/Marklogic/Logs/*.txt (multiple files). I have been able to get the stack running and grabbing the logs from stdout and stderr but when I attach a configmap to my fluentd daemon set to grab the logs from that folder instead of the stdout stderr one the fluentd pod goes into crash loop backoffs and it's logs state.

`2022-07-28 18:30:45 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] /var/log/containers/coredns-64897985d-bvp9g_kube-system_coredns-765e5445d786c5c39b1c2f9bc7cbd561a548f84b0a04233023b779a12c2b0215.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.`

repeatedly for every log file (I assume it's every file). Additionally, the fluentd pod's logs show me the config it is using and it does not include tailing the /var/opt/Marklogic/Logs/ folder at all. Here are my config files for elasticsearch, kibana, and fluentd.

es-config:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      name: rest
    - port: 9300
      name: inter-node
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.0
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      # storageClassName: ""
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 3Gi
```

kibana-config:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5601
  selector:
    app: kibana
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.2.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        env:
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
            value: http://elasticsearch:9200
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
```

fluentd-config:

```
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-config
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
data:
  fluent.conf: |
    <match fluent.**>
      @type null
    </match>
    <source>
      @type tail
      path /var/opt/Markllogic/Logs/*.txt
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      tag kubernetes.*
      format json
      read_from_head true
    </source>

    <filter kubernetes.**>
      @type kubernetes_metadata
    </filter>

    <match **>
      @type stdout
    </match>
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.4.2-debian-elasticsearch-1.1
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "elasticsearch.default.svc.cluster.local"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF
            value: disable
          - name: FLUENT_UID  # change this place
            value: "0"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: fluentd-config
          mountPath: /fluentd/etc # path of fluentd config file
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: fluentd-config
        configMap:
          name: fluentd-config
```

Comment: the log you mentioned is a warning. harmless, not related to fluentd crashing.Please share logs when fluentd crashes.

Comment: You should mount your configuration in /fluentd/etc/conf.d. Your fluentd daemonsets mounts a configmap in /fluentd/etc => this empties the configuration shipping with fluentd image, you removed everything. Also: are you sure that /var/opt/Markllogic/Log folder exists on your hosts? Sounds unlikely/poor implementation if it is, workloads shouldn't log or write stuff directoy to nodes filesystem.

Comment: @SYN yes I'm sure the logs are there, there is a type it is /var/opt/Marklogic/Log one L not two. My goal is to use sidecar to get the logs from there and export them to fluentd's separate container.

Comment: "one L not two" => check back on your confirguration, then. I copy/pasted this from here.